# Multi-lingual comments translation only appears on source language post

Tags: comments, i18n-l10n

I am seeking a patch for Drupal commons to fix an issue with comments to a post not appearing on the translated post as a thread.

So, in simple terms, on the original language post all comments appear. On the translated post no comments appear. I have searched but found nothing so far.